# Convert ashape3d class to mesh3d

Tags: r, rgl

Can somebody help me convert an 'ashape3d' class object to class 'mesh3d'?

In ashape3d, the triangle en tetrahedron faces are are stored in different fields. As I don't think there's a function that can create a mesh3d object from triangles&tetrahedrons simultaneously, I tried the following (pseudocode):

```
model <- ashape3d(rtorus(1000, 0.5, 2),alpha=0.25)

vert <- model$x[model$vert[,2]==1,]
vert <- cbind(vert,rep(1,nrow(vert)))
tria <- model$triang[model$triang[,4]==1,1:3]
tetr <- model$tetra[model$tetra[,6]==1,1:4]

m3dTria <- tmesh3d(vertices=vert , indices=tria)
m3dTetr <- qmesh3d(vertices=vert , indices=tetr)
m3d     <- mergeMeshes(m3dTria,m3dTetr)

plot.ashape3d(model) # works fine
plot3d(m3d)          # Error in x$vb[1, x$it] : subscript out of bounds
```

Does anybody have a better way?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I have updated the question to include some sample data. Unfortunately now it throws an error when using plot3d(m3d). So probably I'm doing something wrong to start with.

Comment: That's the idea of a reproducible example. It should make you think really hard. :)

Comment: I have a feeling there is a mismatch between the points/indices. Do the tmesh3d/mergemeshes functions mess with the number/order of points?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do this recently and found this unanswered question. The easiest way to figure out what is going on is to look at `plot.ashape3d` and read the docs for `ashape3d`. `plot.ashape3d` only plots triangles.

The `rgl` package has a generic `as.mesh3d` function. This defines a method for that generic function.

```
as.mesh3d.ashape3d <- function(x, ...) {
  if (length(x$alpha) > 1)
    stop("I don't know how to handle ashape3d objects with >1 alpha value")
  iAlpha = 1

  # from help for ashape3d
  # for each alpha, a value (0, 1, 2 or 3) indicating, respectively, that the 
  # triangle is not in the alpha-shape or it is interior, regular or singular 
  # (columns 9 to last)

  # Pick the rows for which the triangle is regular or singular
  selrows = x$triang[, 8 + iAlpha] >= 2
  tr <- x$triang[selrows, c("tr1", "tr2", "tr3")]

  rgl::tmesh3d(
    vertices = t(x$x),
    indices = t(tr),
    homogeneous = FALSE
  )
}
```

You can try it out on the data above

```
model <- ashape3d(rtorus(1000, 0.5, 2),alpha=0.25)
plot(model, edges=F, vertices=F)

library(rgl)
model2=as.mesh3d(model)
open3d()
shade3d(model2, col='red')
```